# Join ordered dataframes by nearest match

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have two ordered data frames with events, but some events might be missing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val': [   1.9, 2, 10, 7, 4], 'cat': range(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'val': [5, 2.1, 2,     7, 4, 1.9], 'var': range(6)})
```

In the above example, the expected pairs (`(None,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,None), (3,3), (4,4), (None,5)`) are indicated by the indentation.

Now, I want to outer join the two data frames by `val` as shown in the above example preserving the existing order (so 1.9 in the first df should be paired with the corresponding 2.1 at the same position, not the exact match at the end of the second df).

[`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) requires the two dfs to be sorted by the key (`val`), [`merge_ordered`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html#pandas.merge_ordered) only accepts exact matches.

As a start, I created a list of possible matches:

```
tol = .3
closeness = np.abs(df1.val[:,np.newaxis] - df2.val[np.newaxis,:])
idx = np.vstack(np.where(closeness < tol))

# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4],
#        [1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]])
```

The pairs `3->3` and `4->4` are obvious, but the remaining possibilities make me suspect that it's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Ideally the list of pairs I added (for an outer join), but a if a pure left / right join is easier I can also work with that

Comment: Approximately how long are the two DataFrames?

Comment: @ALollz Generally between 100-800 elements, so a brute force solution isn't out of the question